# Type parameters, upper bounds and overriding

Tags: scala, inheritance, types, pattern-matching

Here's a very simple example:

```
scala> class A(x: Int) {
     |   def withX(newX: Int): A = new A(newX)
     |   override def toString = x.toString
     | }
defined class A

scala> class B(x: Int) extends A(x) {
     |   override def withX(newX: Int): B = new B(newX)
     | }
defined class B
```

So we have two classes:

- `A`, which defines a method `withX` returning the object of type `A`, and
- `B`, which extends `A` and overrides its `withX` method to return the object of type `B`.

Now I'd like to create a container, which can process instances of both `A` and `B`. It should have a method, which can accept an instance of `A` (or `B`), run `withX` on it and return another instance of `A` (or `B`). To be more specific, the exact functionality I want to achieve (note the return types):

```
scala> val a = new A(0)
a: A = 0

scala> val b = new B(0)
b: B = 0

scala> val testA = new Test[A]
testA: Test[A] = Test@4bf59a3d

scala> val testB = new Test[B]
testB: Test[B] = Test@65e565d1

scala> testA.test(a)
res1: A = 1

scala> testB.test(b)
res2: B = 1
```

I suppose that this can be achieved via class with upper-bounded type parameter. I've tried to do it like this, but got an error:

```
scala> class Test[T <: A] {
     |   def test(t: T): T = t withX 1
     | }
<console>:9: error: type mismatch;
 found   : A
 required: T
         def test(t: T): T = t withX 1
                               ^
```

The only workaround I managed to find looks somewhat ugly. Besides that, the `match` clause will need to be rewritten if we add some new class `C` extends `B`:

```
scala> class Test[T <: A] {
     |   def test(t: T): T = (t match {
     |     case b: B => b withX 1
     |     case a: A => a withX 1
     |   }).asInstanceOf[T]
     | }
```

Can this functionality be achieved in more elegant way? I feel like I'm missing something about type parameters, type bounds and all scala type system in general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While it's possible to override a method with a more specific return type, it's rarely a good idea. Consider the following:

```
class C(x: Int) extends A(x) {
  override def withX(newX: Int): B = new B(x)
}
```

This is completely legal, but breaks your assumption that the return type of `withX` is the same subtype of `A` as the (statically known) type of the instance you're calling it on.

You can make that assumption safely (i.e. with support from the type system) by using [*F*-bounded polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_quantification):

```
trait Base[T <: Base[T]] {
  def withX(newX: Int): T
}

class A(x: Int) extends Base[A] {
  def withX(newX: Int) = new A(newX)
  override def toString = x.toString
}

class B(x: Int) extends Base[B] {
  def withX(newX: Int) = new B(newX)
  override def toString = x.toString
}

class Test[T <: Base[T]] {
  def test(t: T): T = t withX 1
}
```

This requires some changes to your type hierarchy, but it's a pretty standard way to encode the idea that the return type of a method is the same as the instance it's called on.

Comment: Thanks for pointing at F-bounded polymorphism, I'll investigate the question. However, there is a requirement in my type hierarchy, that class `B` must extends class `A` (both classes are concrete and have constructor parameters). Actually, my question is based on a real world example, I just heavily simplified the case.

Comment: You're probably out of luck then, and stuck with the cast.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat along the lines of Travis' answer, if you want to encode the fact that a type supports a specific operation (`withX` in this case), you can consider using a type class.

```
class A(x: Int) {
  override def toString = x.toString
}

class B(x: Int) extends A(x)

trait HasWithX[T] {
  def withX(x: Int): T
}

implicit val AHasWithX = new HasWithX[A] {
  def withX(x: Int) = new A(x)
}

implicit val BHasWithX = new HasWithX[B] {
  def withX(x: Int) = new B(x)
}

class Test[T] {
  def test(t: T)(implicit ev: HasWithX[T]): T = ev withX 1
}
```

Example:

```
scala> val a = new A(0)
a: A = 0

scala> val b = new B(0)
b: B = 0

scala> val testA = new Test[A]
testA: Test[A] = Test@4bf59a3d

scala> val testB = new Test[B]
testB: Test[B] = Test@65e565d1

scala> testA.test(a)
res1: A = 1

scala> testB.test(b)
res2: B = 1
```